# Word Games in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

For word games, it is often the frequency of letters in English vocabulary, regardless of word frequency, which is of more interest.

```
 1. >E  11.1607%    56.88   M   3.0129%     15.36
 2.  A  8.4966%     43.31   H   3.0034%     15.31
 3.  R  7.5809%     38.64   G   2.4705%     12.59
 4.  I  7.5448%     38.45   B   2.0720%     10.56
 5.  O  7.1635%     36.51   F   1.8121%     9.24
 6.  T  6.9509%     35.43   Y   1.7779%     9.06
 7.  N  6.6544%     33.92   W   1.2899%     6.57
 8.  S  5.7351%     29.23   K   1.1016%     5.61
 9.  L  5.4893%     27.98   V   1.0074%     5.13
 10. C  4.5388%     23.13   X   0.2902%     1.48
 11. U  3.6308%     18.51   Z   0.2722%     1.39
 12. D  3.3844%     17.25   J   0.1965%     1.00
 13. P  3.1671%     16.14   Q   0.1962%     (1) <-
```

The third column represents proportions, taking the least common letter (q) as equal to 1. The letter E is over 56 times more common than Q in forming individual English words.

How is it possible to build an algorithm is javascript such that if I generate say 100 letters, 11-12% of then i.e. 11-12 letters will be E and so on.

Comment: To be clear, you're choosing random letters but you want the right proportions to match most words?

Comment: yeah.. that is how wed like it..

Comment: suppose we have 10 letters, then atleast one (11/10 = 1) must be an e.

Comment: There are over 1,000 questions about this on Stack Overflow already (according to Google).  What have you tried?  What makes your question unique?  The key words here are weighted random.

Comment: @user3830877: You're mistaking probability for occurrence? "must" is the wrong term.

Comment: im sorry.. i did not know what to search on google exactly.. can you please tell me a short phrase??

Comment: @Brad: If you find an appropriate one, please vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: yeah right.. it must "probably" be an e.. i get you.. but how can this be done..?

Comment: We expect to see code in questions that ask for code. Your question should be more like -- here's the code I have so far, I tried implementing this algorithm but it doesn't work properly, I expect [explain] but it gives me [explain], here's a demo to reproduce the issue [post demo]. How can I fix it?

Comment: yeah fine.. i am new and so i will learn through experience.. an algorithm is as good enough for me though..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an algorithm:

1. Split the range `[0, 1)` in intervals that each matches a letter and has a size proportional to its probability. Eg

   0     - 0.116: E
   0.116 - 0.201: A
   …
2. Get a random number between 0 and 1
3. Pick the interval that contains this number
4. Get the associated letter